# Bootstrap suddenly not working for my React JS project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, package.json

Out of the blue bootstrap has stopped working on my project. I have no idea why.

Here is our package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "blankets",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.26.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.151.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Here is our import in index.html

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Any help/advice/suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: 'stopped working' is a very vague statement of the problem. How has it stopped working? Before and after screenshots, or console log errors are useful.

Comment: Same with my navbar... The answer is right, bootstrap 3 is the answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

is loading the latest version of Bootstrap which is 4.0.0.

And because Bootstrap 4 is totally incompatible with Bootstrap 3 that breaks your layout.

Solution:

Either load the css (as well as the corresponding js) files for Bootstrap 3 OR migrate to Bootstrap 4.

Bootstrap 3 links:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by 'migrate to bootstrap 4'? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Well, Bootstrap 4 is completely different from Bootstrap 3. Manual work will be required to adjust stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, changing back to v3 fixed everything! We're gonna try follow the steps to migrate now, thanks!