# Why stays React Bootstrap Navbar collapsed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I followed the React-Bootstrap documentation, especially this piece of code to make my navbar -> https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-mobile-friendly

However, I cleaned the session of my app from Google Chrome and my navbar seems to stay collapsed.

[image]

I searched the internet without success because I am not really sure what the problem is and where it comes from?

There is my `<Navbar/>`'s code

```
import React from 'react'
import { 
    Navbar as BoostrapNavBar,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    MenuItem,
    NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <BoostrapNavBar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                <BoostrapNavBar.Header>
                    <BoostrapNavBar.Brand>
                        <a href="/">{this.props.navbar_title}</a>
                    </BoostrapNavBar.Brand>
                    <BoostrapNavBar.Toggle />
                </BoostrapNavBar.Header>
                <BoostrapNavBar.Collapse>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                    <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/collections" to="/collections">Collections</NavItem>
                        <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/bracelets" to="/bracelets">Bracelets</NavItem>
                        <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/glasses" to="/glasses">Lunettes</NavItem>
                        <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/watches" to="/watches">Montres</NavItem>
                        <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Support" id="basic-nav-dropdown"> 
                            <MenuItem componentClass={Link} href="/support" to="/support">Messages</MenuItem> 
                            <MenuItem componentClass={Link} href="/new_message" to="/new_message">Contacter le Support</MenuItem> 
                        </NavDropdown>
                        <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/login" to="/login"><img src={'../resources/images/user.png'} alt="User"/></NavItem>
                        <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/shopping_bag" to="/shopping_bag"><img src={'../resources/images/shopping-bag.png'} alt="Shopping-Bag"/></NavItem>
                    </Nav> 
                </BoostrapNavBar.Collapse>
            </BoostrapNavBar>
        );
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome!

## Based on comments:

```
<div id="root">
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header"><a href="/" class="navbar-brand">ShopField</a><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button></div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/collections">Collections</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/bracelets">Bracelets</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/glasses">Lunettes</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/watches">Montres</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a id="basic-nav-dropdown" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Support <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="basic-nav-dropdown">
                            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/support" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Messages</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/new_message" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Contacter le Support</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/login"><img src="../resources/images/user.png" alt="User"></a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/shopping_bag"><img src="../resources/images/shopping-bag.png" alt="Shopping-Bag"></a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div>Home Page</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mate, you need to post your `code` here. You should know that by now. Post the *output* HTML alongside all of the css and JavaScript links by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: Hey @WebDevBooster I was wondering how can I post the code as you asked... Because, it's a full app :/ The only thing I can post is the navbar itself I guess.. As I said, it stays collapse, I mean, it seems like it stays collapsed ...

Comment: Open the page in a browser window, view source, copy and paste HTML.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, right-click in the browser, select "inspect" and then you should be able to get all the output HTML.

Comment: Alright, I inspected and that's what I got in sources, is it what you ask for?

Comment: That's only part of it. To get the HTML contents of the `<div id="root"></div>` you need to right-click the page, select "inspect" and then get the HTML for that part from the web dev console there.

Comment: I just edited my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

At present, React Bootstrap is for Bootstrap 3 only.

To fix your issue, follow the solution I outlined in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48627104/8270343

Once React Bootstrap becomes compatible with Bootstrap 4, the following information will become relevant:

It stays collapsed because you don't have the `navbar-expand-*` class in your navbar. That responsive class tells Bootstrap from which breakpoint onwards the navbar has to expand.

So, if you want it to expand from the `lg` breakpoint onwards i.e. make it expand for screens that are large (`lg`) and larger, then you need to add the `navbar-expand-lg` class to your navbar.

That means: In your case, your react code needs to be adjusted so that this class is included in the HTML output for the navbar.

You'll find more info about this class here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors

Comment: It's weird that the current docs for React Bootstrap only mention options for collapsed or expanded navbars but no option for the responsive behavior that's normally used for websites. If you want the navbar to be permanently expanded you'd use the `navbar-expand` class and React Bootstrap docs do have an option for that.

Comment: Aha! On the home page of React Bootstrap, it says: *"React-Bootstrap currently targets Bootstrap v3. We are actively working on Bootstrap v4"*.

Comment: So, it looks like they haven't yet implemented Bootstrap 4 fully.

Comment: Yep. Here: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/2752 the navbar item is not yet checked. So, it's not done yet.

Comment: I guess, my initial assumption was wrong because you had tagged this with `bootstrap-4`. But I think you'll find the real solution in this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48627104/8270343

Comment: You're perfectly right, thanks for your answers and your links. I just changed the links of bootstrap based on the other stackoverfow answer and it works :) thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working sample of Bootstrap 4.

Pre-requisites:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0
npm install --save reactstrap@next
npm install --save jquery@1.9.1
npm install --save react-transition-group
npm install --save react-popper
npm install react-router-bootstrap --save
```

Make sure you have react-router-bootstrap installed. LinkContainer is the component that will make the link clickable. It must be placed outside of DropdownItem for it to work in Firefox. Also, adding className="collapse" to Collapse component will hide the menu initially in Firefox.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../img/logo_header.png';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Button, ButtonGroup, NavDropdown, Collapse, Navbar, 
    NavbarToggler, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavItem, NavLink,
    Dropdown, DropdownMenu, DropdownToggle, DropdownItem, UncontrolledDropdown } from 'reactstrap';

class MyComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggleNavbar = this.toggleNavbar.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    toggleNavbar() {
        this.state.isOpen = App.myVar.isNavBarOpen; //fixes next time route change where isOpen=true
        let isOpen = !this.state.isOpen; //fixes initial delay in calling setState(), where clicking first time didn't open NavBar
        this.setState({
            isOpen: isOpen
        });
        App.myVar.isNavBarOpen = isOpen;
    }
    render(){
    return (
      <div>            
        <Navbar color="faded" light expand="md">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">
                <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank"><img src={logo} alt="Logo" /></a>
                <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank"><h2 className="header-title">My Site</h2></a>
            </NavbarBrand>                
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} />
            <Collapse isOpen={App.myVar.isNavBarOpen} navbar className="collapse">
              <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                <NavItem><LinkContainer to="/admin"><NavLink>Home</NavLink></LinkContainer></NavItem>
                <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                  <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                    Link 1
                  </DropdownToggle>
                  <DropdownMenu >
                    <LinkContainer to="/sub-link1">
                        <DropdownItem>Sub Link 1</DropdownItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                  </DropdownMenu>
                </UncontrolledDropdown>                    
                <LinkContainer to="/logout">
                    <NavItem><NavLink>Logout</NavLink></NavItem>                                        
                </LinkContainer>
              </Nav>
            </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    )
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

There was bug where if we click on a menu link, the route would change but the NavBar menu would remain open, thus, we needed to use a global variable at the parent Component eg. index.js to manage it's open state.

App.js

```
App.myVar = {
    isNavBarOpen: false
}
```

index.js

```
history.listen((location, action) => {    
    App.myVar.isNavBarOpen = false; //use global variable to manage NavBar isOpen in nested component
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature works fine with react-bootstrap 1.3.0.
It has bootstrap 4.5 with it.