# react-bootstrap could not be able to repeat the official document navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Hi this is my early period of `frontend` skill. I am aware that `bootstrap` is in the transition period from 3 to 4. I decided to follow the latest one. I choose the `react-bootstrap` to my package. If I am doing the wrong way please let me know. I am willing to practice the best solution.

Here is my setup.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "f1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts3-react": "^3.1.0",
    "ajv": "^6.5.0",
    "amcharts3": "^3.21.12",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.0.1",
    "recharts": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.2.3",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

`Header.js`

```
import {Nav, Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

//In render(). Copy from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-mobile-friendly
<div className='container navbar-expand'>
          <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Header>
              <Navbar.Brand className='navbar-brand'>
                <a href="#brand">React-Bootstrap</a>
              </Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle />
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
              <Nav>
                <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
                  Link
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
                  Link
                </NavItem>
                <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                  <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem divider />
                  <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
                </NavDropdown>
              </Nav>
              <Nav pullRight>
                <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
                  Link Right
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
                  Link Right
                </NavItem>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Navbar>
        </div>
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/3.4.0/es5-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/3.4.0/es5-sham.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.32.1/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</html>
```

One thing that different from the original code is I add `container navbar-expand` in order to expand it since [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778460/react-bootstrap-navbar-seems-to-stay-collapsed) said so. That's all I have

**Questions:**
How to repeat the example in my project?
Where is the good resource for newbie like me?

Answer (score 0):

`react-bootstrap` is not yet implementing all the original bootstrap components or newest features. Plus `react-bootstrap` is kind of heavy to use.

I think the solution of simplicity is to add bootstrap classes directly in your jsx content.

Add the bootstrap CDN to your `index.html` or add `import "path/to/bootstrap.min.css";` to your component's source file.

Then you can copy/paste the example from the official bootstrap website and change all `class=""` tags by `className=""`

Hope that can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am searching around on tutorial and example repos. I had tried add CDN and `import` like you said. Therefore it supposed to be somewhere else in my code.